# I am struggling with two issues. I'm trying to add an #id to an html bootstrap card array via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

I'm attempting to build an array of bootstrap cards with json data fields populated inside of the cards. A few of the nested json fields aren't rendering (object Object error). This is the url for the json file which i've stored locally (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users). Additionally I'm attempting to add a unique #id to the card div so that I can manipulate it further (button actions).

What am I doing wrong?

Please be kind as I'm not great with jquery/javascript. This is my first attempt at an HTML array. thanks in advance all.

Screenshot

[image: 1]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    userhtml = '<div class="container">';
    userhtml += '<h1>Users</h1>';
    $.each(valData, function (index, v) {
        if (index % 3 === 0) {
            userhtml += '<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left py-2">';
        }
        userhtml += '<div class="col-md-4">';
        userhtml += '<div class="card m-3" id="">';
        userhtml += '<h2 class="card-header bg-secondary bg-gradient">' + v["name"] + '</h2>';
        userhtml += '<div class="card-body">';
        userhtml += '<h3 class="card-title">' + v["username"] + '</h3>';
        userhtml += '<p class="card-text">' + v["address"] + '</p>';
        userhtml += '<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-remove">Delete</button>';
        userhtml += '</div>';
        userhtml += '</div>';
        userhtml += '</div>';
        if (index % 3 === 2 || index == (valData.length - 1)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            }
            userhtml += '</div>';
        }
    });

    userhtml += '</div>';
    userhtml += '<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-primary">';
    userhtml += '<div class="container">';
    userhtml += '<h2 class="text-light">&#169; 2022 Dan Stump</h2>';
    userhtml += '</div>';
    userhtml += '</footer>';
    $('body').append(userhtml);
    var i = 1;
    $("#user").appendTo(function () {
        $("<div.card />", { "class": "card", id: "user" + i })
            .append($("<div />", { type: "text", id: "user" + i }))
            .append($("<div />", { type: "text", id: "property" + i }))
            .appendTo("card");
        i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could include the code that you're talking about. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yeah, i forgot, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the `object Object` bit is because you're trying to append `v["address"]` to the output html, but address in the data is an object. For the sake of clarity I just added the `street` below, but you could concatenate together whatever properties of address you want. As an aside, you're using square bracket notation like `v["address"]["street"]` where this is easier to write using dot syntax which would be `v.address.street`.

The problem of adding id's, well Im not quite sure what you were doing there but its easy enough to add the unique id from the source data as a property on the `div` - again demonstrated below (although you'll have to inspect the HTML to see it).

```js
const valData = [{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}},{"id":2,"name":"Ervin Howell","username":"Antonette","email":"Shanna@melissa.tv","address":{"street":"Victor Plains","suite":"Suite 879","city":"Wisokyburgh","zipcode":"90566-7771","geo":{"lat":"-43.9509","lng":"-34.4618"}},"phone":"010-692-6593 x09125","website":"anastasia.net","company":{"name":"Deckow-Crist","catchPhrase":"Proactive didactic contingency","bs":"synergize scalable supply-chains"}},{"id":3,"name":"Clementine Bauch","username":"Samantha","email":"Nathan@yesenia.net","address":{"street":"Douglas Extension","suite":"Suite 847","city":"McKenziehaven","zipcode":"59590-4157","geo":{"lat":"-68.6102","lng":"-47.0653"}},"phone":"1-463-123-4447","website":"ramiro.info","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Jacobson","catchPhrase":"Face to face bifurcated interface","bs":"e-enable strategic applications"}},{"id":4,"name":"Patricia Lebsack","username":"Karianne","email":"Julianne.OConner@kory.org","address":{"street":"Hoeger Mall","suite":"Apt. 692","city":"South Elvis","zipcode":"53919-4257","geo":{"lat":"29.4572","lng":"-164.2990"}},"phone":"493-170-9623 x156","website":"kale.biz","company":{"name":"Robel-Corkery","catchPhrase":"Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity","bs":"transition cutting-edge web services"}},{"id":5,"name":"Chelsey Dietrich","username":"Kamren","email":"Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca","address":{"street":"Skiles Walks","suite":"Suite 351","city":"Roscoeview","zipcode":"33263","geo":{"lat":"-31.8129","lng":"62.5342"}},"phone":"(254)954-1289","website":"demarco.info","company":{"name":"Keebler LLC","catchPhrase":"User-centric fault-tolerant solution","bs":"revolutionize end-to-end systems"}},{"id":6,"name":"Mrs. Dennis Schulist","username":"Leopoldo_Corkery","email":"Karley_Dach@jasper.info","address":{"street":"Norberto Crossing","suite":"Apt. 950","city":"South Christy","zipcode":"23505-1337","geo":{"lat":"-71.4197","lng":"71.7478"}},"phone":"1-477-935-8478 x6430","website":"ola.org","company":{"name":"Considine-Lockman","catchPhrase":"Synchronised bottom-line interface","bs":"e-enable innovative applications"}},{"id":7,"name":"Kurtis Weissnat","username":"Elwyn.Skiles","email":"Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz","address":{"street":"Rex Trail","suite":"Suite 280","city":"Howemouth","zipcode":"58804-1099","geo":{"lat":"24.8918","lng":"21.8984"}},"phone":"210.067.6132","website":"elvis.io","company":{"name":"Johns Group","catchPhrase":"Configurable multimedia task-force","bs":"generate enterprise e-tailers"}},{"id":8,"name":"Nicholas Runolfsdottir V","username":"Maxime_Nienow","email":"Sherwood@rosamond.me","address":{"street":"Ellsworth Summit","suite":"Suite 729","city":"Aliyaview","zipcode":"45169","geo":{"lat":"-14.3990","lng":"-120.7677"}},"phone":"586.493.6943 x140","website":"jacynthe.com","company":{"name":"Abernathy Group","catchPhrase":"Implemented secondary concept","bs":"e-enable extensible e-tailers"}},{"id":9,"name":"Glenna Reichert","username":"Delphine","email":"Chaim_McDermott@dana.io","address":{"street":"Dayna Park","suite":"Suite 449","city":"Bartholomebury","zipcode":"76495-3109","geo":{"lat":"24.6463","lng":"-168.8889"}},"phone":"(775)976-6794 x41206","website":"conrad.com","company":{"name":"Yost and Sons","catchPhrase":"Switchable contextually-based project","bs":"aggregate real-time technologies"}},{"id":10,"name":"Clementina DuBuque","username":"Moriah.Stanton","email":"Rey.Padberg@karina.biz","address":{"street":"Kattie Turnpike","suite":"Suite 198","city":"Lebsackbury","zipcode":"31428-2261","geo":{"lat":"-38.2386","lng":"57.2232"}},"phone":"024-648-3804","website":"ambrose.net","company":{"name":"Hoeger LLC","catchPhrase":"Centralized empowering task-force","bs":"target end-to-end models"}}]

$(document).ready(function() {
  userhtml = '<div class="container">';
  userhtml += '<h1>Users</h1>';
  $.each(valData, function(index, v) {
    if (index % 3 === 0) {
      userhtml += '<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left py-2">';
    }
    userhtml += '<div class="col-md-4">';
    userhtml += '<div class="card m-3"  id="' + v["id"] + '">';
    userhtml += '<h2 class="card-header bg-secondary bg-gradient">' + v["name"] + '</h2>';
    userhtml += '<div class="card-body">';
    userhtml += '<h3 class="card-title">' + v["username"] + '</h3>';
    userhtml += '<p class="card-text">' + v["address"]["street"] + '</p>';
    userhtml += '<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-remove">Delete</button>';
    userhtml += '</div>';
    userhtml += '</div>';
    userhtml += '</div>';
    if (index % 3 === 2 || index == (valData.length - 1)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {}
      userhtml += '</div>';
    }
  });

  userhtml += '</div>';
  userhtml += '<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-primary">';
  userhtml += '<div class="container">';
  userhtml += '<h2 class="text-light">&#169; 2022 Dan Stump</h2>';
  userhtml += '</div>';
  userhtml += '</footer>';
  $('#output').append(userhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I owe you a drink Jamiec !